# Random Seed Options

Tags: python

I am very very new to python so please be kind.

I have a python query that is trying to randomize pages to show to the user. So if two people are sitting next to each other and they visit the page they won't see the same results. I seem to be having trouble with the order_list and how it displays. As soon as I add that part in I'm getting back 'no results'.

Maybe it's just a simple typo that I just can't see because I've been looking at it too long?

Any help would be appropriated!

```
filter_class = Filter
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return Serializer
        return Serializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        RANDOM_SEED_OPTIONS = (7,11,13,17,19,23)
        seed = self.request.query_params.get('random_seed', None)
        if seed is None:
            seed = 0
        else:
            seed = int(seed)
        order_list = [
            ('mod_order', 'vo_core_list.id %% %s'),
            ('x_order', 'list_type = %s'),
            ('list_count' ,
             "(select count(id) from vo_core_list c)" )
        ]
        select_list = order_list

        qs =  Consumer.objects.extra(
            select=OrderedDict(select_list),
            select_params=(RANDOM_SEED_OPTIONS[seed]),
            where=["now() BETWEEN Coalesce(display_start,now()) AND display_end"],
            params=Consumer.type,
            order_by=['-x_order','mod_order']
        ).select_related('list_type', 'category',)
        return qs
```

Comment: There is no line of code here that prints `'no results'`.

Comment: Use time for seeding.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm doing that on the cold fusion side when the results come back. It was easier to do it that way.

Comment: @UrielEli I need to use different prime numbers for this. It's not truly random because you could possibly get the same results on a page or on the next page. That is why I am doing it in 'sets' if you know what I mean.

Comment: What is your question? A statement was made ending with a question mark, but it is more a statement of frustration rather than a specific question pertaining to Python.

Comment: @zazvorniki thats what i meant. dont use time for true random. but a random seed will be chosen first each time, leading to identical results over all devices. time gives a different starting point.

Comment: @UrielEli I'm still not quite sure what you're saying? Do you mean instead of the seed options to put a timeit.timeit()?

Comment: Roughly, and it is `time.time()`

Comment: @UrielEli That's interesting...however it really doesn't solve my issue. Im still not getting back any results